# Dialogflow address triggering wrong intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

I've got a order flow that I've setup. I have one intent to get quantity and then I have another to get address. I have the address entity to start by asking for a zipcode/postcode and then a follow up to ask for house number/name.

When I ask for the house number or name my parameters entity is set to sys.any. Because we may get just a house number but could also get something like 'Hill Farm' or 'Flat 4b'. The issue is that when the user inputs a number it actually goes back and triggers the quantity intent which is a @sys.nymber-integer entity. I thought the follow up intent would keep it focused on looking for a house no/name. 
I've carried the context along from the quantity question thinking that it won't ask for it again but it still does so. 
I've changed the entitys from sys.any to sys.number-integer for $houseno and sys.any for $housename. However entering a number still triggers my quantity intent. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use Context to instruct DialogFlow.

**Step 1:**

For the Address Intent train the intent with all the User says data that you have and set an Out-Context - **e.g adress-data**. Add another intent that will capture house number and then add all the User says entries as usual. However also set the In-Context to **address-data**

**Step 2:**

Create your Quantity Intent as you have now and save.